# OS not booting from secondary hard disk

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot

Recently I replaced my Optical Drive with another Hard drive (so it is my secondary hard drive) on my laptop Dell Inspiron 15 3542.

Now I installed my Windows 10 on the primary hard drive and Ubuntu on the secondary hard drive. Windows boots but Ubuntu doesn't.

I replaced my primary hard drive (which contains Windows 10) with the secondary Hard Drive (which contains Ubuntu) now Ubuntu booted successfully but Windows 10 won't boot. I also tried to install Ubuntu on the secondary hard drive and boot files on primary hard drive but I corrupted Windows 10.

Which ever hard drive I put to the primary slot it boots, the other one doesn't. I also tried turning on and off UFEI and Legacy settings in the BIOS but nothing working.

I want to keep my Windows 10 on the primary hard drive and Ubuntu on the secondary hard drive, how should I do it?

Comment: Are you using the bios boot menu to select boot device? F12 at the Dell splash screen.

Comment: Yes i did but there is no option for secondary hard drive.there is option for cd drive which i also tried to get boot from but it isn't working.

Comment: I assume there is a bootable OS on the cd drive bay disk?

Comment: Yes there is bootable OS on both hard drives

Comment: What exactly happens when you select that boot device?

Comment: Hard Disk which i put in place of CD player doesn't boots.

Comment: Even if i put UBUNTU hard disk in primary hard drive slot GRUB is unable to load Windows (present in place of cd drive)(using dual boot) and says no such device.

Comment: Attach an image of bios menu asking for boot device selection.